# Is the right-hand side of C#'s null coalescing operator (??) lazily evaluated?

Tags: c#, lazy-evaluation, null-coalescing-operator

The question's title says it all. In a C# expression `a ?? b`, is `b` always evaluated, or only when `a` evaluates to `null`?

I am curious about this because it might matter in cases when evaluating the right-hand-side expression might have side effects, or when its evaluation might be computationally expensive.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The right-hand side of `??` is lazily evaluated; that is, it gets evaluated only when the expression on the left-hand side has evaluated to `null`. This can be easily tested:

```
bool rhsExpressionWasEvaluated = false;
bool _ = (bool?)true ?? (rhsExpressionWasEvaluated = true);
Debug.Assert(!rhsExpressionWasEvaluated);
```